# Отправка сообщения в не существующий чат Telegram ( Pyrogram )

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyrogram

**Проблема такова, есть у меня клиент Pyrogrm, и есть там список названия групп и их id**

```
groups = [(dialog.chat.title, dialog.chat.id) for dialog in dialogs if dialog.chat.type == ChatType.GROUP and dialog.chat.is_creator]
```

Ну вот он выдал мне например мой чат "Хихихи", получаю его id, пытаюсь отправить сообщение и получаю ошибку `pyrogram.errors.exceptions.bad_request_400.PeerIdInvalid: Telegram says: [400 PEER_ID_INVALID] - The peer id being used is invalid or not known yet. Make sure you meet the peer before interacting with it (caused by "messages.SendMessage")`

Странно, почему pyrogram видит его, а когда я пытаюсь через телеграм найти, телеграм мне его не показывает, следовательно я думаю что нет такого чата, и таких групп у меня несколько, не понимаю как решить...